# Bootstrap 4 - change active status of nav-items

Tags: javascript, navbar

I'm lost with my navbar - I can't figure out how to change an `active` parameter of nav-items in a single main.js.

My navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-info justify-content-lg-center justify-content-md-end">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
  <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='icons/menu_icon.svg') }}" class="img-fluid"
    style="width: 2.0rem; height: auto;" alt="MyWebName">
</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse"
  aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item" id="link_index">
      <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Homepage<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="link_someDropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown1" data-toggle="dropdown"
        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownOfSomething">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url_for('page1') }}">Page 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url_for('page2') }}">Page 2</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" id="link_page3">
      <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('page3') }}">Page 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto justify-content-lg-end">
    <li class="nav-item" id="link_email">
      <a class="nav-link" href="https://gmail.com" target="_blank">E-mail</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: you can use DOM manupulation , when onclick on your item change classes with classList.

Comment: I tried onclick event but after I click on nav-item the new page will load so there is no clicked item. I need something like:
IF page is loaded THEN {
  page_ID = getPageID();
  set active to nav-item with page_id = page_ID;
};